# Formik test returning "You seem to have overlapping act() calls, this is not supported"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, formik, yup

I have a simple form im trying to test:

Form:

```js
<Formik
    enableReinitialize
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        console.log('---DEBUG---');
        onSubmit(values, actions);
    }}
    validationSchema={ValidationSchema}
    >
        {(formik) => {
            const { errors } = formik;

            return (
                <Form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    {/* USER PICKER */}
                    <FastField
                        id="name"
                        name="name"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={({ event, value }) => {
                            handleChange(event);
                            setUserIdOrName(value);
                        }}
                        value={values.name}
                        errorMessage={
                        !!errors.name && !!touched.name
                            ? errors.name
                            : ''
                        }
                        as={TextField}
                    />
                    {/* SUBMIT BUTTON */}
                    <Button
                        color="red"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={() => { console.log('-----CLICKED----'); }}
                    />
                </Form>
            );
        }}
</Formik>
```

Test:

```js
  it.only('shows required error messages', async () => {
    render(<MyForm />);

    const button = screen.getByRole('button');
    userEvent.click(button);

    // Formik and Yup validation are async methods
    const required = await screen.findByText(/required/i);
    expect(required).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Error:

> console.error
> Warning: You seem to have overlapping act() calls, this is not supported. Be sure to await previous act() calls before making a new one.

> ```
> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /required/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
it.only('shows required error messages', async () => {
    render(<MyForm />);

    const button = screen.getByRole('button');
    await userEvent.click(button);

    // Formik and Yup validation are async methods
    const required = await screen.findByText(/required/i);
    expect(required).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: spent a minute playing spot-the-difference here, so to hopefully save someone some time: the `userEvent.click` needs to be `await`ed